# Indent Selected Text With Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I indent each line of the selected text in a textarea control using JavaScript. Something similar to the **Code Sample** button of the **Stack Overflow**'s editor.

**UPDATE:** Viewing the code of **And**, I wrote a solution, but only works with Firefox (also).

The functions is:

```
function indentSelection() {
    var selection, newValue;
    var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
    var start = txt.selectionStart;
    var end = txt.selectionEnd;
    // extend the selecction start until the previous line feed
    start = txt.value.lastIndexOf("\n", start);
    // if there isn't a line feed before,
    // then extend the selection until the begging of the text
    if (start == -1) {
        start = 0;
    }
    // if the selection ends with a line feed,
    // remove it from the selection
    if (txt.value.charAt(end - 1) == "\n") {
        end = end - 1;
    }
    // extend the selection end until the next line feed
    end = txt.value.indexOf("\n", end);
    // if there isn't a line feed after,
    // then extend the selection end until the end of the text
    if (end == -1) {
        end = txt.value.length;
    }
    // move the selection to a new variable
    selection = txt.value.substring(start, end);
    // add four spaces before line feeds
    selection = selection.replace(/^(?=.+)/mg, "    ");
    // rebuild the textarea content
    newValue = txt.value.substring(0, start);
    newValue += selection;
    newValue += txt.value.substring(end);
    txt.value = newValue;
}
```

An example could be:

```
<textarea id="txt" cols="80" rows="8">bla bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla bla</textarea>
<a href="#" onclick="indentSelection();return false;">indent selection!</a>
```

Comment: Find below a solution that supports also IE6.. :)

Answer (score 3):

This works for me on firefox, did not have the chance to test it on other browsers:

```
function indent_selection(){
 var sel_start=document.getElementById("txt").selectionStart;
 var txt=document.getElementById("txt").value;
 var new_txt = txt.split("");
 new_txt.splice(sel_start,0,"   ");
 document.getElementById("txt").value=new_txt.join("");
```

}

html:

```
[...]
  <textarea id="txt">bla bla bla....</textarea>
  <a href="#" onclick="indent_selection();">indent selection!</a>
[...]
```

**UPDATE:** cross-platform solution!

Find [here](http://jsbin.com/ijedi) a textarea indent script that works also in IE6 - i've not tested it on IE7 though..  **Credits:** I've simply merged Kiewic's code with the getTextAreaSelection function found on [Jerson Maglasang's blog](http://jmaglasang.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/textarea-selectedtext-selectionstart-selectionend-selstart-selend-ie-and-firefox/).

Comment: The split and the join method: Do you really use the empty string or is your text just a victim of the SO editor?

Comment: no, these are really empty strings... BTW: I actually really like the SO editor!

Comment: I want to indent the beginning of each line, not just the beginning of the selection, but your code has been useful for me. Thanks!

Comment: thank you, i've stuck in this whole day hhe .

Answer (score -2):

Unless it's a div that is dressed up as a textarea you would have to use bunch of empty spaces I suppose

Comment: I suppose, you're wrong. A textarea acts just like a pre element, that is, it shows *every* whitespace in its content.

Comment: agreed it is empty space - it was late last night, let me fix the comment

Comment: Guy asked how to indent text in the text box, I'm saying it can be done with empty spaces, but you can keep the point for teaching me to be more careful with my answers :)